# Protractor is returning the object instead of the value when traversing using xpath in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xpath, protractor

I'm new to protractor. I'm using it to get the value from the table using the xpath. When i run the below code, It is returning me the object instead of td value

Protractor Code:
var result = element(by.xpath("//tr/td[@style='min-width:51px']"));
        console.log("+++++++++++++++++"+ result);

Output:
+++++++++++++++++[object Object]

HTML Page:

```html
<div class="ng-scope" ng-include="'product/main/views/ABC.html'" ng-if="context.pat">
 <section class="module module-pat product-banner ng-scope" ng-controller="product.main.PBS">
 <figure class="pat-photo pull-left">
  <table class="table-overview pull-left">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td style="min-width:225px">
     <td class="ng-binding" style="min-width:51px">F</td>
     <td class="ng-binding" style="min-width:61px">56</td>
     <td class="ng-binding" style="min-width:130px">1958-03-13</td>
     <td class="ng-binding" style="min-width:115px">Welby</td>
     <td class="ng-binding" style="min-width:178px">United</td>
     <td class="ng-binding" style="min-width:80px">Yes</td
     <td>
      <span class="label label-important ng-binding"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <th class="pat-number ng-binding">123456789 </th>
    <th class="ng-binding">Sex</th>
    <th class="ng-binding">Age</th>
    <th class="ng-binding">DOB</th>
    <th class="ng-binding">PCP</th>
    <th class="ng-binding">Country</th>
    <th class="ng-binding">Insurance</th>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 element(by.xpath("//tr/td[@style='min-width:51px']")).getText().then(function(result)
 console.log("+++++++++++++++++"+ result);
 });
```

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your answer to include a description why this answers the question.